# on the zariski closure and cocompactness of discrete groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Assume $\Gamma$ is a discrete subgroup of some $GL_n$, and let $G$ be its Zariski closure. 
Let $H$ an algebraic cocompact normal subgroup  of $G$. Do we have that $H\cap \Gamma$ is of finite index in $\Gamma$.
I'm not sure this is true (actually i think it should be false), i'm far from being an expert in this field, and i don't have any couterexample yet.

Many thanks

Comment: Can you define a Zariski discrete subgroup, which is not finite?

Comment: thanks for your answer. "Can you define a Zariski discrete subgroup, which is not finite?", i can't :) . i'm not sure i really get your counterexample. in this case $\overline{\Gamma}^{Zar}$ should be the lower unipotent matrices with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$ (am i right ? ), and $H$ is not a cocompact subgroup ?

Comment: Assuming your field is real or complex numbers, the statement is true. The point is that modulo a compact normal subgroup of $G$, the group $H$ has finite index in $G$.

Comment: Sorry I confused H being cocompact in GL(n) versus in Gamma:(

Comment: But neverthe less you should be precise. Closure of something discrete is trivial, since discrete implies closed. The Zariski topology is $T_1$.

Comment: Do you mean discrete in the analytic topology of $GL_n(F)$ for $F$ being a local field. I guess, this is what Misha interpreted?

Comment: @MarcPalm: That would be the only reasonable (and quite common) interpretation.

Comment: yes i'm sorry. when i said discrete, i meant with the usual topology not with the Zariski's topology, and when speaking of cocompactness of $H$ in $\overline{\Gamma}^{Zar}$ i mean the usual one as well. One more time, thank you for your help

Comment: Okay, then you need to specify the field in the first place. Glad that I could help to clarify the question.

Comment: the field is the field of real or complexe numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true. There are irreducible (arithmetic) lattices $\Gamma=G({\mathbb Z})$ in $$SL _2({\mathbb R})\times SU(2)=G({\mathbb R})$$ such that $\Gamma$ projects densely into $SU(2)$ and its projection to $SL_2({\mathbb R})$ is a cocompact lattice. $G$ is an algebraic $\mathbb Q$-subgroup of $GL_n$ and the Zariski closure of $\Gamma$ is not $H= SL_2({\mathbb R})$ but it is $G({\mathbb R})$. $H$ is an algebraic co-compact normal subgroup of $G({\mathbb R})$ but its intersection with  $\Gamma$ is only the trivial element.

Comment: Do you really want to say Gamma = G(Z)?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. The formulation "There are..." followed by naming a specific lattice confused me;)

Comment: this is not a specific lattice; there are many $\mathbb Z$ structures on $G({\mathbb R})$.